# How can I get the horizontal and vertical resolution of a bitmap?

Tags: android

I am trying to find the bitmap horizontal and vertical resolution (dpi). I need this information to properly clip my bitmap. I already have the width and the height of the bitmap and this is the only missing information. The (wrong) output that I am getting is the clipping is off. Here is my example. It is marked by "(Missing)" in the code where I would need the Bitmap vertical and horizontal resolution.

```
final Bitmap clippedBmp;
final Rect<Double> clipRectInInches = imageScaleInPixelAndInches.getClipRect();
final Rect<Integer> clipRectInPixel = new Rect<Integer>();

clipRectInPixel.setX     ((int)(clipRectInInches.getX()      * (Missing)));
clipRectInPixel.setY     ((int)(clipRectInInches.getY()      * (Missing)));
clipRectInPixel.setWidth ((int)(clipRectInInches.getWidth()  * (Missing)));
clipRectInPixel.setHeight((int)(clipRectInInches.getHeight() * (Missing)));

ClipRectUtil.normalizeClipRect(clipRectInPixel, orgBmp.getWidth(), orgBmp.getHeight());
clippedBmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(orgBmp,
                                         clipRectInPixel.getX(),
                                         clipRectInPixel.getY(),
                                         clipRectInPixel.getWidth(),
                                         clipRectInPixel.getHeight());
```

here is the normalizeClipRect function

```
public static void normalizeClipRect(Rect<Integer> clipRectInPixel, int imgWidth, int imgHeight)
{
    int clipX      = clipRectInPixel.getX();
    int clipY      = clipRectInPixel.getY();
    int clipWidth  = clipRectInPixel.getWidth();
    int clipHeight = clipRectInPixel.getHeight();

    if ( clipX < 0 )
        clipX = 0;
    if ( clipY < 0 )
        clipY = 0;

    if ( clipX > imgWidth )
        clipX = imgWidth;
    if ( clipY > imgHeight )
        clipY = imgHeight;

    if ( clipX + clipWidth > imgWidth )
        clipWidth = imgWidth - clipX;
    if ( clipY + clipHeight > imgHeight )
        clipHeight = imgHeight - clipY;

    // update in-place
    clipRectInPixel.setX     (clipX);
    clipRectInPixel.setY     (clipY);
    clipRectInPixel.setWidth (clipWidth);
    clipRectInPixel.setHeight(clipHeight);
}
```

I thank you in advance. Please let me know if more information is needed.

Thanks again,

Marc

Comment: Oops, pardon me. I've edited my commented because I just realized you already have the bitmap loaded. The Bitmap class has methods for getting the dimensions. Bitmap.getHeight() and Bitmap.getWidth().

Comment: Sigh. Gotta read slower. You're already able to get the dimensions in pixels, you want it in dpi. I need a coffee break. Sorry Marc.

Comment: Lol, np TJ. I do that all the time. I do appreciate the help though. There are so many links on getting the dimensions does not seem to be any answered ones for the resolution.